# Is it possible for a 3rd party app to video call a teams user?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like a Teams user to video call an other Teams user using external hardware (usb camera) and using mobile devices (android first).

> What can Teams apps do?
>
> ...
>
> Collaborate on items in external systems. One of the core scenarios
>   for a custom Teams app is to bring information or items into Teams
>   from some other place, and have a conversation around it. You can push
>   information into Teams, enable your users to search for and pull it on
>   demand, or **make it available in an embedded web view**.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview?view=msteams-client-js-latest)

I guess I could develop a small web application and a server which could act as a bridge.
Android app streams a video to my webserver, teams web app loads video stream from my server. **Could that work?**

I've found some other people asking similar things, and they did not get an answer.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/SDK-for-Microsoft-Teams/m-p/261008

The easiest would be, if teams had a real sdk, but it seems to me, that it only has support for very limited "plugins".

Comment: Teams mobile clients already have the ability to call other users, but only with the internal hardware. You want to do this with external hardware? (BTW this scenario will never work with iOS devices because Apple doesn’t support external video devices.)

Comment: Yes. I have to use external hardware. I don't care about iOS in this case... But you saying that iOS does not support external video devices is false. Flir has thermal cameras for the iPhone.

Comment: Currently this is not supported in Teams.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT please post your comment as an answer. I would like to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently This is not supported in Teams.